# Moved /etc folder to another place

Tags: directory, etc

I moved /etc folder to another place.
Now when i use `sudo mv` command it says:

```
sudo: uid 1010 does not exist in the passwd file
```

there's a solution for it?
it happenned in my vps by ssh. Format isn't an option.
(ubuntu VPS)

Comment: Ejem.... Why?  If you still have a root shell you can try to symlink `/etc` back. Or if  you have physical access you can use a rescue disk/USB. Otherwise... Bad prognosis.

Comment: it is VPS how could i do a simlynk?, moved etc/ folder to /var/www/old/

Comment: From a root shell, you can just `ln -s /var/was/old/etc /etc`. But you need a root shell you opened *before* you did the move; now there is no way to acquire superuser privileges short of a physical access.

Comment: ln: creating symbolic link `/etc': Permission denied

Comment: @hoheckell It's a VPS? Time to backup your data, and reinit (if it was real hardware, and you had physical access, you could boot single user and move the files back - without root access you cannot).

Comment: Was an accident with mv / command ... :(

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the way users are authenticated for login on Ubuntu is with the `/etc/passwd` file. Since that file is missing... bad things are going to happen, such as sudo not working.

If you have root access somewhere, such as a session you still have open, or you can figure out how to get in as root, you can make a `symlink` (which is similar to a shortcut on Windows) to the new location so that the operating system can find the file. You do this with the `ln` command. The syntax would be:

```
ln -s [your new /etc location] /etc
```

Comment: ln: creating symbolic link `/etc': Permission denied
can't get root access
sudo: uid 1010 does not exist in the passwd file!

Answer (score 1):

[image: Meme]

Now, for repairing your current system, you can do:

1. Boot to a Live environment.
2. Mount your current Ubuntu partition:

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt
   ```

   **Change XY to your current Ubuntu partition**. If unsure launch Gparted from live environment and look for something like `sda1`, `sda2`, `sda3`, etc.
3. Copy the `/etc` back to its place i.e., `/mnt/path/to/moved/etc` to `/mnt/etc` **Copy it with `sudo`**.
4. Exit.

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```
5. Now after you have booted to your installed system, you can delete the previously moved `/etc` folder.

Comment: Nice --- ;-) --- but the problem is, they have a VPS, so no physical access to the machine. No boot to a rescue environment...

Answer (score 0):

This is what you did by moving `/etc` away without an open shell with privileges:

[image]

Image from: https://i.stack.imgur.com/syj9u.jpg

... The only way out is to reset the VPS after a backup. Sorry. Remember, with `sudo` come great power and great responsibility...